# SecurityTrimming does not hide unauthroized menus

Tags: kendo-menu, security-trimming

I have a Kendo menu that is built dynamically.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Menu()
        .Name("menu")
        .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "menu-top", styles = "max-height:55px" })
        .SecurityTrimming(s => s.HideParent(true))
        .Items(menu =>
        {
            foreach (var item in Model.Where(m => m.mnu_Parent_ID == null))
            {
                var builder = menu.Add().Text(item.mnu_Title);
                addChildren(builder, item, Model);
            }
        })
```

and calls this function:

```
public void addChildren(MenuItemBuilder builder, workflow.ViewModels.Home.MenuViewModel item, List<workflow.ViewModels.Home.MenuViewModel> items)
    {
        var children = items.Where(m => m.mnu_Parent_ID == item.mnu_ID);
        if (children != null)
        {
            builder.Items(menuItems =>
            {
                foreach (var child in children)
                {

                    var menuItem = menuItems.Add().Text(child.mnu_Title).Action(child.mnu_Action,child.mnu_Controller).LinkHtmlAttributes(new { onclick = "ShowRequestForm('" + child.mnu_Title + "','" + child.mnu_URL + "'," + child.mnu_ID + ",-1," + child.mnu_flowID + ",'" + child.mnu_OpenWindow + "'," + prs_ID + ",-1,-1 );" });
                    addChildren(menuItem, child, items);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

I want to hide the menus base on user's roles. But the `.SecurityTrimming(s => s.HideParent(true))` does not hide the menus that user is not authorized for them.
**Is the problem for building dynamic menu or not having the `sitemap` ?**